# Effect of sex at specific point with confidence interval without centering

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

Assume I model PEFR (related to lung function) as a function of sex and height:

```
summary(lm(PEFR ~ sex*height, data))
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      -2.387    232.790  -0.010   0.9918  
sexmale        -128.864    306.362  -0.421   0.6750  
height            2.871      1.402   2.048   0.0433 *
sexmale:height    1.074      1.796   0.598   0.5512
```

With confidence intervals

```
> confint(lung_i)
                       2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)    -464.41126123 459.637600
sexmale        -736.90742615 479.178849
height            0.08869134   5.653358
sexmale:height   -2.49037241   4.638737
```

So for people with height = 0, the effect of sex is around -129 [-737; 479]. Now, height = 0 is obviously not that interesting, so what if I'm interested in the effect of sex for height = 170?

I know I can center height at 170, to obtain the estimate and confidence interval in a similar manner (see below), but is there any way to get the estimate and CI without centering?

Thanks in advance!

````
> lung_i <- lm(PEFR ~ sex*I(height-170), data)
> summary(lung_i)
[...]
Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              485.687      9.968  48.725  < 2e-16 ***
sexmale                   53.747     14.704   3.655 0.000417 ***
I(height - 170)            2.871      1.402   2.048 0.043263 *  
sexmale:I(height - 170)    1.074      1.796   0.598 0.551168    

[...]

> confint(lung_i)
                               2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)             465.90382978 505.470976
sexmale                  24.56366568  82.929714
I(height - 170)           0.08869134   5.653358
sexmale:I(height - 170)  -2.49037241   4.638737
```
````

Comment: Look into the R package [`effects`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=effects). Using the argument `fixed.predictors` you can fix height to 170. Another useful package is [`visreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=visreg) which offers the argument `cond` to set predictors to a certain value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! It seems that the `effects` package is able to give me the estimates for each sex (similar to what I could get from `predict(...)`), but I'm not sure how to find the difference between sexes. Of course the point estimate of the difference is easy to get, but I also want to know the confidence interval, which appear to be the tricky part.

Comment: @Sextus Please don't use comments for such polemics.  If you want to discuss SE policy, do so on a meta site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans):

```
library(emmeans)

mod <- lm(Lacmax~Sex*Age, data = dat)

summary(mod)

em <- emmeans(mod, "Sex", by = "Age", at = list(Age = 35))

summary(contrast(em, "pairwise", at = list(Age = 35)), infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))

Age = 35:
 contrast estimate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 m - f        2.21 0.558 135     1.11     3.31 3.958   0.0001 

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The output gives the estimated difference between males and females at age 35 including a confidence interval and a $p$-value.

Adapting this for your example:

```
em <- emmeans(lung_i, "sex", by = "height", at = list(height = 170))

summary(contrast(em, "pairwise"), infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks!